# Using AMI ID created by CodeBuild in CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm currently playing around in my AWS environment (CodeCommit, CodeBuild, and CodePipeline) and was wondering how would I be able to pass the AMI ID of an EC2 created by CodeBuild into my CloudFormation template. Of course I'm able to copy and paste the AMI ID into the CloudFormation template, but in the spirit of DevOps and CI/CD, is there a more automated way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you do, but if you create your AMI in CB, and then want to provision a CFN template out of it in an automated manner, you would setup a **deploy action** in your CodePipeline with [AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CloudFormation.html) provider.

The provider has `ParameterOverrides` parameter which would allow you specify the AMI id from CB as one of the parameters for the CFN deployment. In order to do so, in CB you would export the AMI Id as one of its [output variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeBuild.html#action-reference-CodeBuild-variables).

Comment: Awesome thanks! The second part of your response is what I was looking for as I had already set up the deploy action in CodePipeline.

Comment: @DogeCloud No problem. Glad I could help.